# “Far hamlets to the east will know his antics”

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

> He will pass beyond it through those desolate plains, and over the
>   hills beyond them, beyond Bapaume. Far hamlets to the east will know
>   his antics.
>
> And one day surely, in old familiar garb, without court dress, without
>   removing his hat, armed with that flexible cane, he will walk over the
>   faces of the Prussian Guard and, picking up the Kaiser by the collar,
>   with infinite nonchalance in finger and thumb, will place him neatly
>   in a prone position and solemnly sit on his chest.

This is from the novel *[Tales of War](https://archive.org/details/taleswarbylordd02dunsgoog)* by Lord Dunsany

*Far hamlets to the east will know his antics.* I do not understand the meaning. It might mean that he (Charlie Chaplin in the film) will go to Kaiser Wilhelm.

I am glad if somebody might give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is reiterating that he will travel far to the east.  I am not familiar with the geography from the novel, but it is clear that there are settlements far out, perhaps on the outskirts of the territory.  Even these far away settlements will know about him because he will travel so far.

An example might help clarify how the sentence is being used.  Instead of a person traveling, consider a ball traveling across a football/soccer field. The purpose of the sentence in question is similar to the purpose of the italicized sentence below:

The goal tender will kick the ball beyond his box.  He will kick it beyond midfield.  *Far spectators behind the opposing goal will be able to see specks of dirt on the ball.*